# Spark Dataframe upsert to Elasticsearch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, elasticsearch

I am using Apache Spark DataFrame and I want to upsert data to Elasticsearch
and I found I can overwrite them like this

```
val df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("/mnt/data/akc_breed_info.csv")

df.write
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
  .option("es.port","443")
  .option("es.net.ssl","true")
  .option("es.nodes", esURL)
  .option("es.mapping.id", index)
  .mode("Overwrite")
  .save("index/dogs")
```

but what i noticed so far is this command `mode("Overwrite")` is actually delete all existing duplicated data and insert the new data

is there a way I can `upsert` them not delete and re-write them ? because I need to query those data almost real time. thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

The reason why `mode("Overwrite")` was a problem is that when you overwrite your entire dataframe it deletes all data that matches with your rows of dataframe at once and it looks like the entire index is empty for me and I figure out how to actually `upsert` it

here is my code

```
df.write
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
  .option("es.nodes.discovery", "false")
  .option("es.nodes.client.only", "false")
  .option("es.net.ssl","true")
  .option("es.mapping.id", index)
  .option("es.write.operation", "upsert")
  .option("es.nodes", esURL)
  .option("es.port", "443")
  .mode("append")
  .save(path)
```

Note that you have to put `"es.write.operation", "upert"` and `.mode("append")`

Comment: What is the value of the `index` ?

Comment: @Soumendra it's `mapping id` of ES as shown. For me, it's `userId`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting:

```
es.write.operation = upsert
```

This should perform the required operation. You can find more details in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html

Comment: thanks for answering. I tried that but it didn't work for me and I needed to put `.mode("append")` too

Comment: While this is correct, you need to set the mode to "append" otherwise all the existing documents will be removed from the index.